# Which responsibilities should repository finder methods have?

Tags: domain-driven-design

## TL;DR

Should a DDD repository:

- perform generic searches refined later by a domain services?

`findAllByPurchaseId(purchaseId)`

- or maybe detailed searches tailored to a specific use case?

`findAllOfPurchaseDueBefore(purchaseId, limitDate)`

- do additional simple calculations (like summing)?

`amountExpectedToBePaidBefore(purchaseId, limitDate)`

## Background of the question

My domain model has two aggregates:

- `Purchase(purchaseId)`
- `Installment(purchaseId, dueDate, amount)`

In one of my application services I have to answer the question about the total installment amount expected to be paid before a certain date.

Initial `InstallmentRepository` implementation (Groovy + Grails + GORM + Hibernate):

```groovy
def findAllByPurchaseId(purchaseId) {
    Installment.executeQuery(
        'from Installment where purchaseId = :purchaseId', 
        [purchaseId: purchaseId]
    )
}
```

The application service did further filtering and calculation:

```groovy
def amountExpectedToBePaidBefore(purchaseId, limitDate) {
    def installments = installmentRepository.findAllByPurchaseId(purchaseId).
        findAll { it.dueBefore limitDate }
    installments*.amount.sum()
}
```

I realised that my application service had domain logic - it did additional filtering and calculations. On the other hand my repository seemed to be too *DAOish* - it did simple aggregate access without any additional business value.

I consider **two refactoring options**:

1. place the filtering by `dueDate` in the repository and sum amounts in a domain service
2. do everything in the repository (amount sum is a simple calculation)

Since a repository should be mimicking a specialized collection of aggregates, with the API based on the ubiquitous language, option **2.** is more appealing to me.

#### Which abstraction/detail level should a DDD repository have?

- Should it perform generic searches, used by possibly many services?
- Should/could repository finders be application service/use case specific?
- Is it OK to have additional (though simple) calculations in a repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. The Domain repository queries are usually GetById(). It's not a hard rule, but this is what domain needs 99% of time. Don't re-use the domain repository interface for presentation/reporting queries. That is, the concrete class can handle everything but the abstraction should be tailored by the context needs.
2. If the Domain needs that yes, the repository method gets a criteria to work with.
3. If processing doesn't require business rules then it's ok. However that's not really a repository semantic, that's a service which happens to be implemented in DAL. So yes, but don't call it a repository :)

Comment: Same conclusions my team and I reached.